# Global Variable and store it in Session

Tags: asp.net

In win applications we can declare a Variable that access it in all of current form(sth like below code)

i want to fill a dataset in Page Load and keep dataset in `Session` and use it later

Is there any problem about memory in this way?(means if at a same time 100 user come to site and i should keep 100 dataset in Session)

```
namespace Store
{
    DataSet ds; // Global DataSet
    public partial class frmLoading : Form
    {
    //...
```

Comment: Careful about global variables in asp.net. An asp.net app is a single app serving multiple users, so all users see the **same** value. In a winform situation each user has his own instance of the app and so their own values.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Cache class` in order to share your data `(Global Cache)`

So with Cache you can use just one DataSet.

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx

Session is dedicated for each conneted user

Comment: When you connect to application you have session cache where you save your datas, another user can not access to this session, because it's proper to session , but with Cache you access datas of another user because is global cache

Comment: thank you,but my question is if 100 user come to my website and i keep 100 dataset with 1000 records to `Session` is there any problem about memory?

Comment: yes you can have problem with your memory, is uggest you to instal memory profiler in order to prospect you memory, link : http://memprofiler.com/?gclid=CP7owYP59bICFeTHtAodunsAkA

Comment: how can i keep a dataset and use it in current page that i fill dataset in page load?

Comment: you bind with GridView control, link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/vstudio/fkx0cy6d.aspx